# Make parent div sortable, not children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="nestedQuestionGroup">
  <div class="formsection">
  </div>
  <div class="formsection">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nestedQuestionGroup">
  <div class="formsection">
  </div>
  <div class="formsection">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nestedQuestionGroup">
  <div class="formsection">
  </div>
  <div class="formsection">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make `#nestedQuestionGroup` sortable and not the childs within It? The current sortable-function from jquery-ui makes the child sortable, not the parent itself.

Comment: How you want to sort one element?

Comment: Ya, really not clear what you are asking?!

Comment: @Mohammad: What? It's gonna be multiple nestedQuestionGroup

Comment: @A.Wolff: It's gonna be multiple nestedQuestionGroup's

Comment: @Bryan So make their common closest ancestor sortable...

Comment: Do you want to sort by `jquery-ui`?

Comment: @A.Wolff: Ofc.. Thank you.

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmSgx/247/)

Answer (score 0):

From based documentation on jqueryui sortable widget (http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/), you should try to do this :

html :

```
<div id="parent-sortable">
    <div class="nestedQuestionGroup">
        <div class="formsection">
        </div>
        <div class="formsection">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nestedQuestionGroup">
        <div class="formsection">
        </div>
        <div class="formsection">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nestedQuestionGroup">
        <div class="formsection">
        </div>
        <div class="formsection">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js :

```
$( "#parent-sortable" ).sortable({
     items: "> .nestedQuestionGroup"
});
```

You can personalize your sortable with many options like delay, cursor, opacity, axis, classes, etc...

Hope it helped !

Comment: You don't need the custom `items` option. Just making the common parent a sortable will "sort" the immediate children only